# JMLR.cls package: wrong behavior of \thanks

Tags: footnotes, titles, journal-publishing, affiliation

It looks like this is a rare thing, since I found no references in internet regarding this issue.

I use JMLR.cls style file, and I want to introduce two authors with different `\thanks` references and with different (of course) symbols. However they appear to obtain the same symbol.

Using MacTeX (TeXLive 2014) the minimal example is the following

```
\documentclass{jmlr}

\title{Title}
\author{Author 1\thanks{Thanks 1}
    \and
    Author 2\thanks{Thanks 2}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

which produces
[image]
[image]

What could be the problem, any hints to the potential errors would be appreciated!

`\thanks` a lot!
Alex

**UPD:** for me the `\nametag` somehow didn't work as well, hence the question.

Comment: Bug now fixed. I've just uploaded version 1.21 to CTAN. It may take a few days to get into the TeX distributions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following addition to your preamble - before making calls to title macros - fixes the problem:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thanks}[1]{%
  \footnotemark
  \protected@xdef\@thanks{\@thanks
    \protect\footnotetext[\arabic{footnote}]{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

The problem is that the footnote mark is set with the `\author`s, but never transferred to the footnote text (stored in `\@thanks`). As such, the default footnote mark is used since it's not specified.

[image]

```
\documentclass{jmlr}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thanks}[1]{%
  \footnotemark
  \protected@xdef\@thanks{\@thanks
    \protect\footnotetext[\arabic{footnote}]{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author 1\thanks{Thanks 1}
    \and
    Author 2\thanks{Thanks 2}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @Werner ! That worked for me! Marking as answer.