# jmlr.cls - hyperref author notes and \thanks command

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, titles, author, affiliation

I use the jmlr class and have issues with the `\thanks` command which seems to be related to a known `hyperref` limitation with respect to footnotes (see the [LaTeX wiki book](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes#Common_problems_and_workarounds)). Note that this questions is also a follow-up of a previous one ([JMLR.cls package: wrong behavior of \thanks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229295/)) but points out different problems.

My first minimal example is as such:

```
\documentclass{jmlr}

\title{Title}
\author{\Name{Author Name1\nametag{\thanks{Thanks 1}}}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

It produces the following warning and the hyperlink does not work in the pdf file:

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Further to this, I am trying to make use of a shared footnote to indicate joint authorship and followed the steps indicated in the [LaTeX wiki book](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes#Common_problems_and_workarounds). The minimal example for this is as such:

```
\documentclass{jmlr}

\title{Title}
\author{\Name{Author Name1\nametag{\thanks{Contributed equally}
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\addtocounter{Hfootnote}{-1}}}
\and
\Name{Author Name2\nametag{\footnotemark}}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

This produces the desired visual output in the pdf but generates the same warning as above also with missing hyperlinks in the pdf. I have read through a number of posts (e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/) but couldn't find a workable solution yet so help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: To give the broader picture and in case this gets solved later on through a different channel, this is related to an issue filed on the MIDLLatexTemplate GitHub project: https://github.com/MIDL-Conference/MIDLLatexTemplate/issues/1